# Getting Dynamic (Runtime) Buttons in WP7 to Associate with Objects

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, button, dynamic

I am creating an interface for an XNA game and can't seem to figure something out.  I'm new to programming, and feel like I have to be missing something obvious.

I'm creating a grid of levels, much like something you'd see in Angry Birds.
The number of levels will be variable, so I don't want to statically program them.

All of the buttons I use for level icons are created dynamically at runtime, based on a list of level objects.  As I create the buttons I set up all of the click events to point to one method that is supposed to determine which button they clicked on, and load that specific level.

**My problem is I can't seem to figure out a reliable way to actually tell which button they clicked on and associated that with one of my level objects in the list.**  I feel like I must be missing something extremely obvious.

**Things I've tried so far:**

As I generate the buttons dynamically I add them as children to a grid.  So I tried using the index number of the sender as the index number in my list of levels (because they should both have the same number of elements).
For example:
App.CurrentLevel = PuzzleLevelsGrid.Children.IndexOf(sender as Button);

This worked great the first time I navigate to the level picking screen, but whenever I come back to it the children of my grid gets reset to a count of 0 for some reason, so it breaks down.
I've set break points and I can't explain how it gets set to 0.  I load the children in my onNavigatedTo(), and sometime between the end of that and me pressing a button to load a level it gets wiped.

The other thing I tried was setting up a button object inside my actual level object, then when dynamically creating the level buttons I actually make changes to the button property in the appropriate level.
Then when I need to find out which button was the sender I just loop through all levels and match the sender to the button property.  This method actually worked pretty well... until I started trying to load my levels using a background worker thread.  The worker thread can't deal with the Button because it's a UI thread thing, and crashes.

Like I said, I'm a new programmer, so I welcome any and all feedback.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button, like almost every UI control, has a "Tag" property. This property has been designed for you, and only for you, so that you can put any value you like to identify the control.

For instance, you can put your level object in the Tag property of the button, then just read this value back in the click event.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I've been looking around online and can't seem to find any examples of this tag in use.  Could you give me a simple example of what that tag looks like?
Is it just a container of sorts that I can dump information into?

Comment: It's just a property of type 'object', you can put whatever you want inside. When creating the button, set the tag: `button.Tag = myLevelObject;`. Then, in the click event, retrieve it: `var myLevelObject = ((Button)sender).Tag as Level;`

Comment: Thank you so much KooKiz.  I knew I had to be missing something.  I know this was probably obvious to any experienced programmer, but you saved me a lot of time and frustration.  
Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, a surprisingly small amount of devs know of the Tag property, as it seems useless at first glance.